# Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': parameter 1 is not of type 'ImageData'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Below is my html code, and it gets the error: 
"Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': parameter 1 is not of type 'ImageData'."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script>
  const data = new Uint8ClampedArray([255, 0, 0, 1]);
  const ctx = document.querySelector("#c").getContext("2d");
  ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I looks like you missing something. try wrapping your Uint8ClampedArray with an imageData object as such: `const myimg = new ImageData(data, 100, 50)` (the 100 represents the width of the canvas, 50 is height) and now you should have a real imageData stream (unlike Uint8ClampedArray which is a binary array and NOT and imageData object)

Comment: @Max Svid yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 main problem in your code, and 1 extra small problem in your code.

**Main problem**

[`.putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) requires [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) as its first argument. Instead, you gave a `Uint8ClampedArray`.

To solve this, you need to create an `ImageData` instance with the `Uint8ClampedArray`:

```
data = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray([255, 0, 0, 1]), /* other required params */);
```

**Extra problem**

In your `Uint8ClampedArray`, you have an array `[255, 0, 0, 1]`. This data actually converts to `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.005)`. In other words, your little red box will be rendered with alpha of 0.005, almost transparent.

To make it opaque, you need to convert the alpha into scale of 255.

For example, if you want a 1x1 opaque red box, you need to give `[255, 0, 0, 255]` to the `Uint8ClampedArray`.

**Example**

See below example of a 2x2 half transparent (alpha of 0.5) red box.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const data = new Uint8ClampedArray([
  255, 0, 0, 128,
  255, 0, 0, 128,
  255, 0, 0, 128,
  255, 0, 0, 128
]);

const imageData = new ImageData(data, 2, 2);

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, [putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) expects an ImageData object like:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#c");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
  imageData.data[i + 0] =
    imageData.data[i + 1] =
    imageData.data[i + 2] = (i % canvas.width) % 256;
  imageData.data[i + 3] = 255; // A value
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```